# Nom qui serait le plus approprié pour certaines petites affiches du type utilisé sur YouTube

Tags: expressions, demande-de-mot

Par exemple sur YouTube le moyen d'annoncer aux utilisateurs ce qu'une vidéo contient consiste à faire figurer une petite affiche comme les suivantes.

[image]

Je ne connais pas de nom pour nommer ces sortes d'annonces. Les mots de sens général ne semblent pas pratiques (annonce, affiche, publicité, prévues), et un terme spécifique, s'il existait, serait apparemment utile. Est-ce que quelqu'un connaitrait un terme usuel ?

Answer (score 7):

On appelle ça des **vignettes**, des **miniatures** ou des **aperçus** (en particulier quand on passe la souris dessus).

> *On entend souvent parler de thumbnail sur YouTube, mais savons-nous  exactement ce que cela signifie et quelle est son importance ? Eh bien, c’est un outil indispensable dans le monde de la vidéo sur YouTube. Communément appelé vignette ou miniature en français, il s’agit d’une image de taille réduite extraite de la vidéo qu’elle présente. En d’autres termes, c’est l’équivalent de la couverture d’un livre dans l’univers de la vidéo en ligne. Mais quelle est l’utilité des thumbnails et comment les concevoir ?*
> [Tout savoir sur les thumbnails sur YouTube](https://www.megazap.fr/Tout-savoir-sur-les-thumbnails-sur-YouTube_a9340.html)

> ***Ajouter des miniatures de vidéos sur YouTube**
>
> Les miniatures donnent un aperçu de vos vidéos aux spectateurs. Vous pouvez choisir l'une des miniatures générées automatiquement par YouTube ou importer la vôtre si votre compte est validé*
> [Support Google](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/72431)

> **Aperçus vidéo**
> Les aperçus vidéo vous permettent de voir un extrait de trois secondes d'une vidéo avant d'en lancer la lecture.
>
> Lorsque vous pointez sur la miniature d'une vidéo (sur ordinateur) ou que vous faites défiler la page des résultats de recherche (sur mobile), un aperçu de trois secondes s'affiche. Une fois la lecture de l'aperçu terminée, la miniature de la vidéo s'affiche.
> [Support Google](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7074781?hl=fr)

Answer (score 3):

Aussi *imagette(/[vignette/miniature](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/53050/26366)) de vidéo*. ([Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=VIDEO%20THUMBNAIL&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs))

Hormis l'*imagette* et le [*titre*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/53049/26366), il s'agit simplement de *suggestions* de vidéos.

Answer (score 1):

C'est le [titre](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/titre) de la vidéo.  (Mon emphase en gras)

> Définition de titre nom masculin
>
> 1. Nom donné (à une œuvre, un livre) et
>    qui évoque souvent son contenu. Le titre d'un roman, d'un recueil de
>    poèmes.
>    Donner un titre à. ➙ intituler.
>    Page de titre, portant le
>    titre, le sous-titre, le nom de l'auteur, etc. Faux-titre : titre
>    simple sur la page précédant la page de titre. Des faux-titres.
>    Titre
>    courant : titre imprimé en haut ou en bas de chaque page d'un ouvrage.
>    par extension Les meilleurs titres de l'année.
>    **Le titre d'une chanson,
>    d'un film, d'un tableau.**
> 2. **Expression, phrase qui présente un article
>    de journal.** ➙ rubrique. Titre sur cinq colonnes. ➙ manchette. La
>    nouvelle fait les gros titres de tous les journaux.

Comment: Le titre fait partie de l'ensemble ; c'est le nom de l'ensemble qui est demandé ; iI y a même un bout de la vidéo dans cet ensemble ; Ce n'est pas une page non plus, dans le langage de la Toile, une page rempli tout l'écran ; avez-vous une référence qui dise que le mot « titre » est le nom qui est donné à l'ensemble ? Ça me surprendrait mais sait-on jamais. Comment appelleriez-vous cet ensemble en anglais ? « Title » ?

Comment: _du vidéo_? Pas plutôt _de la vidéo_?

Comment: Quand on parle du cinéma ce sont des titres.

Comment: @Frank Vidéo: [*Au Québec, en particulier dans la langue orale, il est couramment employé au masculin.*](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/25315/la-grammaire/le-nom/genre-des-noms/genre-du-nom-video)

Comment: @jlliagre Bien reçu. Intéressant.

Comment: @jlliagre Même pas avocat (que je sache) t'es avocat dans le propre sens.  Ad + vocare c'est déjà 19/20 ( :

Comment: Je suis même parfois l'avocat du diable ;-)